# Getting an image from value of src in <img> tag and submitting it to <input type="file"> via javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a HTML form that allows an user to upload an image, like this:

```
    <form method="POST" action="/somewhere">
    <input type="file" />
    <input type="submit" />
    </form>
```

My question is:

i) How to choose an image that's in html(img) tag and select it at input element with type="file" only using javascript  and submit the form without user having to fill out and click anything?

Or to understand my question, assume that you're embedding a file in value="".
[EDITED]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That will depend on where this image comes from. If from a different origin, you're kinda stuck, otherwise,

```
fetch(img.src) // fetch the image resource
  .then(r => r.blob()) // as blob
  .then(blob =>{
    cont form = new FormData(); // create a FormData
    form.append('file', blob, filename); // add the blob, I let you define the filename
    // post it to your server
    return fetch('/somewhere', {method:'POST', body:form});
  }).then(r => console.log('sent'));
```

Here I am using ES6 syntax and [fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API), but same could be done with [XHR](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest).
Docs on [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/FormData).

Answer (score 0):

For security reason, you cannot set default for input[type="file"]

Comment: Can I send the image via HTTP Request?